# If I am travelling on a train (departs at 6pm from my place) to a state that's 608 KM away from mine, can I pray Maghrib and Isha the next day?

Tags: salat

I am travelling on a train that travels for 12 hours.

It starts from my state before Maghrib and reaches the destination the next day after Fajr.

Will my salah still be valid if I pray my missed Maghrib and Isha the next day along with Fajr?

Edit: Considering that it's almost difficult to pray in the train, will my salah still be valid if I pray my missed Maghrib and Isha the next day along with Fajr?

Comment: Scholars nowadays regard not praying in a plane or while seating as rather invalid (incomplete). In a train you'd have much more space to pray than in an airplane.

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualykum,

If you are a musafir(traveller) on a journey and are moving constantly, you should pray your salah at its alloted time and try to face the qiblah. Then the next day, pray the farz and witr again of Maghrib and Isha along with Fajr and Inshallah this will suffice if your previous salah on the train were'nt accepted.

Also, as you are travelling, you will only need to pray Qasr (shortened salah). This means only the farz and witr and only 2 rakaats farz for Isha.

PLEASE NOTE THAT THESE MASLAH ARE FROM THE HANAFI MAZHAB